# Printing a Exported svg of original size in paper.js

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs

I'm using a paper.js for creating a web based editor like Adobe Illustrator.
Issue which i'm facing  is when i import a svg file which is quiet large then my canvas and when i try to print that svg using

```
newWindow.write("`<html><body>`"+paper.project.exportSVG();+"`</body></html>`")'
newWindow.print();
```

it covers the only part that is visible to canvas.

i also tried to zoom out the canvas using zoom-factor , but at that time there is a issue of original size of the svg.
though the dimensions are quiet large  it can be cover within the a4 size page easily.

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in the library, or a case of missing options. Could you open an issue for it on https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues ? That's the better place to discuss this.

Comment: Actually, I believe it's just a question of passing the right options to `exportSVG()`. The documentation is currently lacking. I've created an issue for this already: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1254